# How to persist an ASP:Table with TextBoxes inside cells?

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.Table whose cells are containing textboxes filled by the user.

When he clicks on a button, I want to store textboxes content into a database but in the onclick event, the table is empty. How can I persist the whole table, and especially the textboxes data ?

Comment: Tried to store it in the viewstate

Comment: Post the code you have so far so we can amend and help

Comment: My code is too big and complex to put it there but my problem is really simple to explain : I have one asp:table which contains textboxes inside its cells (everything has been added programmatically). I have also one asp:button triggering an onclick event. I would like to retrieve my textboxes values in this event, which currently is impossible as all the asp:table has gone empty (postback).

Comment: OK - good luck getting help without posting code :)

Comment: I don't understand, I'm not asking to give me a code, I'm asking for a simple advice about which way is better to perform what I want : using the viewstate with a custom serializable class ? using the viewstate with a serialized asp:table ?

Answer (score 0):

Create a name value collection corresponding to the columns and rows of the table. Store each cell value as a part of the name value collection in the DB with the name in the form of r1c1, r1c2, etc.

Comment: Actuallty my problem is to retrieve those values, so that I could store them after. I can't retrieve them as when I push the button, the table becomes empty.